# How to store image uploaded from form as featured image in post?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have an html form in front end in WordPress page. A user uploads the image in the form which should be set as featured image in CPT. 
This is the upload field in the form:

```
<input id="uploadBtn" type="file" class="upload" name="uploadBtn"/>
```

I have tried this code :

```
// Add Featured Image to Post
$image_url        = 'http://s.wordpress.org/style/images/wp-header-logo.png';// Define the image URL here
$image_name       = 'wp-header-logo.png';
$upload_dir       = wp_upload_dir(); // Set upload folder
$image_data       = file_get_contents($image_url); // Get image data
$unique_file_name = wp_unique_filename( $upload_dir['path'], $image_name); // Generate unique name
 $filename         = basename( $unique_file_name ); // Create image file name

// Check folder permission and define file location
if( wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir['path'] ) ) {
$file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
} else {
$file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
}

 // Create the image  file on the server
  file_put_contents( $file, $image_data );

  // Check image file type
  $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, null );

  // Set attachment data
  $attachment = array(
      'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
      'post_title'     => sanitize_file_name( $filename ),
      'post_content'   => '',
      'post_status'    => 'inherit'
  );

  // Create the attachment
  $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $new_post_id );

  // Include image.php
  require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

  // Define attachment metadata
  $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );

  // Assign metadata to attachment
  wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

  // And finally assign featured image to post
  set_post_thumbnail( $new_post_id, $attach_id );
```

It works well if I have image url, name and such. However, I need to make it work for any image that user uploads. Is there any way to get image url and name from $_FILES? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need either post object or post ID for the `set_post_thumbnail()` function. The function `wp_insert_post()` will return post id on success. You can use that post id to set the thumbnail image.

Here is the modification for your last couple of lines

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

if(!$post_id){
    // post insertion was failed. Handle it here
}

//Set Image as thumbnail
set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attach_id);
```

Comment: I have the post ID, it is $new_post_id. Can you tell me how to get the url and name of the image uploaded through form?

Comment: $attach_id = media_handle_upload($files, $post_id);                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 $attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attach_id);

Comment: I'm getting a " Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function media_handle_upload() " error.